# Hibernate: Deserialize String to Value

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I have a string in a database that corresponds to the string value of an enum.  I would like to tell Hibernate that this string should be regarded as a value from the enum class.  Something like calling

```
 MyEnum.valueOf(stringName);
```

How do I do this in my hibernate xml mapping file?

Right now I have this:

```
<class name="com.example.SomeObject" table="some_object">
    <id name="id" column="id" />
    <property name="someEnum" column="value"/>
</class>
```

But I do not believe this is working, and I suspect may be related to this stack trace

```
ERROR 11-03 08:07:54,458 -Servlet.service() for servlet example threw exception
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 494E5445
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:223)
at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:180)
at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:211)
at org.hibernate.type.SerializableType.fromBytes(SerializableType.java:105)
at org.hibernate.type.SerializableType.get(SerializableType.java:62)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:184)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:173)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:105)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2124)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1404)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1332)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1230)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:603)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
```

Comment: I guess this might be the non annotation equivalent.  Plus this is about the xml specific declaration needed, not wrapper classes.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
<property name="someEnum" column="columnName">
    <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
        <param name="enumClass">com.example.SomeEnum</param>
    </type>
</property>
```

Then the enums go in an out by string value.